# Product rule or chain rule?

Tags: derivatives

Does one take the product rule or chain rule when there are 3 terms with variable being multiplied together.

example

taking
$$ x = r\cdot \cos \theta \cdot \sin \phi $$

at an instant in time

$$ x(t) = R(t) \cdot \cos\theta(t) \cdot \sin\phi(t)  $$

to derive in order to obtain

$$ \dot{x}=R'(t) \cdot \cos'\theta(t) \cdot \sin'\phi(t) $$

I'm leaning towards product rule because

$$ f'(x)g(x)h(x) + f(x)g'(x)h(x) + f(x)g(x)h'(x) $$

but just doesn't seem to be coming out right.

I end up with

$$ \big(1 \cdot \cos\theta (t) \cdot \sin\phi (t)\big) + \big(R(t)\cdot (-\sin\theta (t) )\cdot \sin\phi (t)\big) + \big(R(t)\cos\theta (t) \cdot \cos\phi (t) \big) $$

Comment: Are $\theta$ and $\phi$ functions of $t$?  That is should they be $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t)$, so you have $\cos(\theta(t))$ and $\sin(\phi(t))$? Also, use `\sin` and `\cos` for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: When taking the derivative with respect to $t$ all the other variables are constant.

Comment: Thank you @JohnOmielan. That was what I've been looking for. 


\theta and \phi change when t changes. 
The values for (R,theta,phi) = (25,-120,15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly that $$x(t) = r(t)\cos(\theta(t))\sin(\phi(t))$$ then you will need both the product and chain rules to differentiate with respect to $t$.  You will get
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &= r'(t)\cos(\theta(t))\sin(\phi(t)) - r(t)\sin(\theta(t))\theta'(t)\sin(\phi(t))\\[5pt] &\quad + r(t)\cos(\theta(t))\cos(\phi(t))\phi'(t).
\end{align*}